# VB.Net ComboBox - Enums and Limiting Values Based on Selection in Another ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, enums

The project I'm working on makes extensive use of Enum's to hold unit symbols. Like this...

```
Public Enum AreaSym
    unknown = 0
    in2
    mm2
End Enum
```

My Problems began when I realized that my Enum names didn't make good names for the drop downs on my ComboBoxes.  I found and implemented a TypeConverter from this C# CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LocalizingEnums.aspx?msg=3746572 ...  It allows you to assign the Enum Values friendly names in a .Resx file, and it overloads the GetValues function so that it returns the Enums friendly names from the .Resx file.  This works well as I can then assign the combobox data source directly to the enum.

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(AreaSym))
```

However, I realized that when using a Datasource in this manner, I have to manipulate the data source to create a change in the ComboBox.  Such as, if I don't want to display unknown to the user, I'd need another way to load my ComboBoxes.  This is when I decided to make a List(Of KeyValuePair(AreaSym, String))

```
Public Function AreaSymbols() As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of AreaSym, String))
    AreaSymbols = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of AreaSym, String))
    AreaSymbols.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of AreaSym, String)(AreaSym.in2, "in²"))
    AreaSymbols.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of AreaSym, String)(AreaSym.mm2, "mm²"))
    Return AreaSymbols
End Function
```

This is great because now I can control exactly what goes into the combo box using the list.

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = UnitNameList.AreaSymbols
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
```

However, I've found that using a DataSource has stopped me from doing two things.

1. When the form loads, I want the ComboBox itself to show as either empty with no text, or to show the Text I've input in the Text Property.  Currently using the DataSource, it always is populated with the first item in the list.
2. I'd like to be able to easily limit the items in the list, based on the selection of items in another list.   Classic example would be two ComboBoxes filled with the exact same values (1,2,3) & (1,2,3).  When you choose 1 in ComboBox one, only (2,3) are available for selection in ComboBox 2.

I realize that I could probably easily do that if I was using Items, instead of a data source, I'm just not sure what the best way to do that would be because of my need to have the key, value pair of enums and strings...

Comment: Also, I think I found part of my problem :)  This appears to be a bug, has anyone found a way around this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx

Comment: I see this is almost a month ago - did you get this resolved or find a workaround?

Comment: I changed my expectations of combo boxes and just made things work.  For example instead of adding a text input in the text property, if I wanted something to show up first in the list, I'd add that as the first item in my data source.  Such as <Select> as the top item etc.  Feels kind of wrong, but it works.  Second thing is started to use filtering to write queries, so if item 1 is selected, write a query to show everything except item 1 in combo 2.

Comment: A hack is better than nothing. =)